# Tengo la siguiente consulta compleja en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql, microsoft, microsoft-sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una columna de productos donde tiene los siguientes campos, product, article, product_state, event_date, necesito basicamente filtrar solo los eventos donde se cambio el estado.

Adjunto el ejemplo de como necesitaría la salida, espero que me puedan ayudar por favor, hasta el momento no he podido con ninguna técnica, he probado con el row number pero no logro el resultado esperado.

Comment: Hola Diego, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son.  aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.

Comment: Además de lo que ya te han indicado, viendo los datos, hay algo que no encaja. Dices donde se cambio el estado. Esto vale, tanto en cuanto el 18340 tiene cambios de estado. Peo empezando por 4166 la primera fila del excel marcada en verde. ¿Porqué es la primera? Los datos no tienen orden, y por lo que muestras no está ordenado por ningún criterio. En cuanto le pongas una función que ordene, tipo row_number, se ha trastocado todo tú ejemplo. Por eso es necesario un escenario completo. Con los datos y como los obtienes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde la versión 2012 de SQL Server, esta consulta es más sencilla. Necesitas usar la función LAG() para obtener un valor de una fila anterior (por default, la inmediatamente anterior pero puedes saltar varias filas).

Aquí hay un ejemplo de como se puede ver.

```
SELECT  product, 
        article, 
        product_state, 
        LAG( product_state) OVER( PARTITION BY product, article ORDER BY event_date) prev_product_state,
        event_date
FROM Productos
ORDER BY product, 
        article, 
        event_date;
```

Sin embargo, para poder usar esa columna en el WHERE y filtrar los datos, necesitamos pasarlo a una subconsulta o CTE.

```
WITH cteProductos AS(
    SELECT  product, 
            article, 
            product_state, 
            LAG( product_state) OVER( PARTITION BY product, article ORDER BY event_date) prev_product_state,
            event_date
    FROM Productos
)
SELECT  product, 
        article, 
        product_state, 
        event_date
FROM cteProductos
WHERE product_state <> prev_product_state 
OR prev_product_state IS NULL;
```

Dependiendo de los datos, es probable que también se pueden usar los otros argumentos de LEAD para asignar un valor default y quitar la condición del NULL. Esta opción es más peligrosa porque podemos asignar un valor que no se use actualmente, pero pueda ser usado más adelante.

```
WITH cteProductos AS(
    SELECT  product, 
            article, 
            product_state, 
            LAG( product_state, 1, 0) OVER( PARTITION BY product, article ORDER BY event_date) prev_product_state,
            event_date
    FROM Productos
)
SELECT  product, 
        article, 
        product_state, 
        event_date
FROM cteProductos
WHERE product_state <> prev_product_state;
```